# Looking for real-world DJI Phantom 3 Professional sample geo-tagged images for testing

Tags: data, imagery, digital-image-processing, photogrammetry, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am looking for sample DJI Phantom 3 Professional imagery for testing purposes with the [Drone2Map for ArcGIS Beta](http://www.esri.com/products/drone2map) software. So far I am finding the application very polished and easy to use but I am running it on the sample datasets provided by ESRI which maybe be very clean and "ideally" suited for this software.  I would like to purchase the above-mentioned UAV do do 3D models and simple volumetric calculations for small sites. I would like to make sure that the software (which will no doubt be a very expensive yearly subscription) does in fact work as well with real world data. I would also like to run some test on some open source software packages some of which are [mentioned here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79403/are-there-any-open-source-tools-for-the-processing-of-uav-images).

Answer (score 2):

OpenDroneMap has some sample data. You can give it a try: [OpenDroneMap](http://opendronemap.github.io/odm/#)

Comment: Thanks. Specific for the DJI P3?  do you use the OpenDroneMap software for processing data?

Comment: @Jakub I think its a good alternative. but you need linux

Answer (score 1):

We have a large amount of example UAV and Drone imagery available at: https://dronemapper.com/sample_data

or

https://dronemapper.freshdesk.com/solution/articles/2100019855-example-dji-aerial-nadir-imagery-data-collections

A few of the data sets are from our DJI Phantom 3 Advanced and they are available for all uses (including commerical)